# DOM content update with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say that I have:

```
<h1>{{number}}</h1>

<input type="button" value="click me" ng-click="clicked()">

$scope.number = 0;
$scope.clicked = function() {
    $scope.number += 10;
    console.log($scope.number);
};
```

In the Javascript console, the number changed to 10, but in the header it's still 0....

Comment: Can you post more of your source - including the controller being applied to this page?

Comment: @danielrsmith:it looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/3es6c/

Comment: Looks like that works: http://jsfiddle.net/sMBVC/